# How did Cohen invent forcing?

Tags: set-theory, math-history, forcing

A couple of popular maths book, I forget which stated that Cohen invented Forcing.

Now, generally I've noticed that there is a history which allows one in hindsight to show that how certain techniques invented beforehand could be seen to lead upto a new technique like Forcing.

What techniques could Cohen have been influenced by to invent Forcing?

Comment: The following article may be of interest: Paul Cohen, _The discovery of forcing_, Rocky Mountain Journal of Mathematics 32 (2002), no.4, pp.1071--1100, [Project Euclid link](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1181070010).

Comment: You can read by Akihiro Kanamori, *COHEN AND SET THEORY* (The Bulletin of Symbolic Logic, 2008), but also in Dov Gabbay & Akihiro Kanamori & John Woods (editors), *Handbook of the History of Logic, vol 6: Sets and Extensions in the Twentieth Century* (2012), ch.1: *Set Theory form Cantor to Cohen*, again by Kanamori.

Comment: I'd also add Dana Scott's Foreword to John Bell's *Set Theory, Boolean-Valued Models and Independence Proofs*, which explicitly address this issue.

Answer (score 4):

I found [*A Beginner’s Guide to Forcing*](https://arxiv.org/abs/0712.1320) by Timothy Chow very helpful in explaining how forcing was invented. It’s online and only 16 pages long.

> An important insight of Cohen’s was that it’s useful to consider what he called *standard models* of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $. A model $ (M,R) $ of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ is **standard** if and only if the elements of $ M $ are well-founded and the relation $ R $ is ordinary set membership.

...

> The somewhat counter-intuitive fact that $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ has countable models with many missing subsets provides a hint as to how one might go about constructing a model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $ satisfying $ \neg \mathsf{CH} $. Start with a countable standard transitive model $ M $.

...

> Consider a function $ F $ from the Cartesian product $ \aleph_{2}^{M} \times \aleph_{0} $ into $ 2 = \{ 0,1 \} $, where $ \aleph_{2}^{M} $ denotes the element of $ M $ that plays the role of the second uncountable cardinal. We may interpret $ F $ as a sequence of functions from $ \aleph_{0} $ into $ 2 $. As $ M $ is countable and transitive, so is $ \aleph_{2}^{M} $; we can thus arrange for these functions to be pairwise distinct. Now, if $ F $ already lies in $ M $, then $ M $ satisfies $ \neg \mathsf{CH} $.

...

> However, what if $ F $ is missing from $ M $? A natural idea is to add $ F $ to $ M $ to obtain a larger model of $ \mathsf{ZFC} $, which we might denote by $ M[F] $. The hope would be that $ F $ can be added in a way that does not ‘disturb’ the structure of $ M $ too much.

The careful creation of $ M[F] $ is called *forcing*.

Comment: This explains the idea behind the mechanics of forcing. But not the historical context from which Cohen could have come up with the technique itself.

Comment: True. I interpreted the question as how did Cohen conceive of Forcing? I believe the article gives a good context for that.

Comment: @kibble: thanks for the reference.

Comment: I like Yurii, and I appreciate him hosting the text, but using an arXiv version is better.